# Apex dynamically assign new records to users using trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, user-record, assignment-rules

I'm a young Apex developer. I have a quick question:

I would like to dynamically assign new records to users using an Apex trigger. As we know, every new created records are automatically assigned to the current logged in user.

I am trying to create a trigger that assigns the leads between the 2 users equally. The solution should count the number of leads assigned to each user, so that we have similar number of leads assigned to each user.

For  example:
- You have User C and User D
- You mass insert 7 lead records
- Leads 1, 3, 5 and 7 are assigned to User C
- Leads 2, 4 and 6 are assigned to User B

Comment: As an alternative, have you thought about using a [Lead Queue](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=queues_overview.htm&language=en_US) and letting the Reps pull from there?

Comment: You could also use Lead Assignment Rules. Possibly in conjunction with lead queues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is called "round robin" assignment.

1) If you want to custom build it, you can find the approach on a similar question that I've answered for Cases and Accounts [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/29184/round-robin-auto-assignment-of-related-account-on-case-object-with-before-insert). You would need to do the same thing for the users and leads.

2) There is an app called "Round Robin Record Assignment" on the [appexchange](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000178fsEAA), I personally haven't tried it, but looks like it does what you need and it's free.

3) You can also achieve this by creating a couple of custom fields and assignment rules. A very good example can be found [here](http://www.shellblack.com/administration/create-a-round-robin-lead-or-case-assignment-rule/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I will look to this and back with the answer.  Thank you !